# WebSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode does nothing in KitKat 4.4.x

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

Or maybe I'm missing something that has changed in 4.4.x but here are my findings. As a disclaimer I have read the migration "documentation."

The website has the following (and only) viewport meta tag in :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=900, height=600, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

My WebFragment has a WebView with the following settings:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setUserAgentString(webSettings.getUserAgentString() + Constants.USER_AGENT);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

On pre-4.4 the website zooms out to fit the WebView content area (which is not full screen). On 4.4.x, the website remains zoomed in. The WebView has `WRAP_CONTENT` for width and height.

Changing the `initial-scale` in the viewport and setting the initScale on the WebView, will zoom out the webpage, but that is a hack solution for some that the `setLoadWithOverviewMode` should be doing.